# POST and models not matching - causing MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I inserted new model fields into my existing model in Django yesterday. This is how it looks:

[image]

Then I ran these two commands-

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

In my views.py I try to get from the post request all the added fields, but it gives me this error:

[image]

When I look into the POST itself I see that none of my new fields were added!

[image]

I understand that the fields are non-exsistent in the new request.POST, so the error pops in this part of the code:

```
def updaterecord(request, id):
      group_name = request.POST['group']
      sale_rent = request.POST['sale_rent']
      street = request.POST['street']
      city = request.POST['city']
      rooms = request.POST['rooms']
      size = request.POST['size']
      floor = request.POST['floor']
      porch = request.POST['porch']
      storage = request.POST['storage']
      mamad = request.POST['mamad']
      elevator = request.POST['elevator']
      parking = request.POST['parking']
      price= request.POST['price']
      phone= request.POST['phone']
      date = request.POST['user_date']
```

I just don't understand how to solve this, is there any updates or commands I need to make?
I don't remember how I solved it last time or how to avoid it in the future.
Help please :-)

Additional Information-
the sqliteDB does have all the fields in it, so this is how my main website looks...

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you could put your code as text in your question rather than embedded images. It also seems that the issue is how your fields are presented in your template and therefore if/how they are sent via `request.POST`, it doesn't appear to be a migration issue.

Comment: in "template" do you mean my Html templates?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, solved the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error!
Make sure in the HTML you are using the value under the input "name" matches the field your trying to get in the POST request!!!

Answer (score 0):

Html tag attributes / View with strings hardcoded / your model attributes should always be intact, and this could be considered as complexity from a maintenance perspective.

Take a look at django model forms, or at simply at django forms.